# Spring Social: Is user logged in

Tags: spring-security, spring-social

I want to implement following flow:

1. User goes to Login page
   "Login with Facebook" button displays there
2. User logins with his Facebook account
   "Login with Facebook" button disappears
   "Logout" button appears

I have implemented everything I want, except displaying of controls depending on user signed in or signed out.

How I can do this on JSP level? Which variables I need to put in  tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [**authorize** tag](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e3022) from Spring Security taglib in conjuction with [SpEL expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#el-common-built-in):

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    Logout button goes here
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
    Login button goes here
</sec:authorize>
```